# Referring to abstract type outside of trait for class construction

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, abstract-type, library-design

Premise:

I want to separate the information necessary to instantiate a class from the information necessary to "run" the class. However, the information neccesary to "run" the class may differ from class to class. Thus, I imagine the class "has" specific information to run it, and the two go together.

Here is an example of my code:

```
trait Machine {
  type Params <: BaseParams

  def start(machineParams: Params): Unit
}

trait BaseParams {
  def speed: Int
  def power: Int
}

class FlyingMachine() extends Machine {
  type Params = FlyingParams

  override def start(machineParams: Params): Unit = {
    println(s"I'm flying with $machineParams")
  }
}

trait FlyingParams extends BaseParams {
  def height: Int
}


abstract class MachineOwner{

  val machine: Machine

  def params: machine.Params

  def startMachine(): Unit = {
    machine.start(params)
  }
}
```

This compiles, passes tests, I'm happy.

Problem: I'm using `val machine: Machine` in order to define `def params: machine.Params`. I've been told to make this a `def` to let the implementer have more freedom. If I do so, I can no longer refer to `machine.Params`

At this point, I'm at a loss for how to continue. I keep thinking that if this should be a `def` and definitely not a `val`, then my architecture is wrong.

So

1. Is my approach to this problem wrong, given the premise I set out with?
2. If it's not wrong, is there a way to still achieve this while using `def` instead of `val` in the `MachineOwner` class?

**EDIT** 
Given Alexey Romanov's answer, the last bit of the code would look like this

```
abstract class MachineOwner{

  type Params1 <: BaseParams

  def machine: Machine { type Params = Params1 }

  def params: Params1

  def startMachine(): Unit = {
    machine.start(params)
  }
}

class FlyingMachineOwner(
  machine: FlyingMachine
) extends MachineOwner {

  override type Params1 = FlyingParams

  override def params = FlyingParams(1,1,1)
}
```

But this doesn't compile because it expects an override specifically for `def machine: Machine { type Params = Params1 }`. How does one define that?

Comment: What does `Factory` actually produce? It seems like a tuple with two constants and a method that returns a `Unit`?

Comment: Ugh, I'll update the code. I didn't mean to name it `Factory` after the Factory builder pattern. It was just a small example. Imagine that it's job is just to manage  `machine`. Start it, maybe stop if it an external event comes in, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really can't be answered without knowing desired semantics.

If `MachineOwner` is supposed to own a single machine, then "to make this a def to let the implementer have more freedom" is bad advice: the freedom it gives is exactly to return different machines from different calls to `def machine` and not to hold references to machines it gives out.

If it is supposed to have multiple machines, should all of them have the same `Params` type? Then you would do something like

```
abstract class MachineOwner{

  type Params1 <: BaseParams

  def machine: Machine { type Params = Params1 }

  def params: Params1

  def startMachine(): Unit = {
    machine.start(params)
  }
}
```

Or if not, then you need a different design again, maybe `def params(machine: Machine): machine.Params`. Etc. etc.

For the edit: you *can* do

```
class FlyingMachineOwner(
  _machine: FlyingMachine
) extends MachineOwner {

  override type Params1 = FlyingParams

  override def params = FlyingParams(1,1,1)

  override def machine = _machine
}
```

but it really seems unnecessarily complicated compared to what you get with type parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ideally, each `Machine` has its own `Params` type. To continue my example, there could be a `UnderwaterMachine` that has another parameter `SeaParams`  that add things like oxgyen level, etc.

My alternative solution is just to make `params` and optional field in `Machine`, and then just throw a `require` in my start before the code executes. But that forces a runtime violation versus a compile time violation, which rubs me slightly the wrong way. Hence me trying to leverage type safety.

Comment: "each Machine has its own Params type" Yes, but that's different from the question "does each Machine returned by the same MachineOwner have the same Params type".

Comment: Ohhh, I get it. Yes, each Machine returned by the same MachineOwner does have the same Params type". That question just helped clarify the difference. Let me fiddle with my code, and see what this changes for me.

Comment: Edited my question with your suggestion. Am I missing how I should be overriding `machine`? This is my first run-in with type refinement.

Comment: Because `Params1` is defined inside, `machine` has to be as well :( I'd suggest using type parameters instead of type members for both `Machine` and `MachineOwner`.

Comment: Alrighty. I was afraid that would be the final answer. I'm torn between getting this to work on compile time and using the type members for design time vs instantiation time typing, but I'll opt for the former over the latter.

Comment: I've added code which should work for this case to show it's possible.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct @Alexey, because I believe you've demonstrated the best possible scenario with the parameters provided. Thanks for the effort.